# Regression estimate outside bounds of bootstrapped 95% confidence interval

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am fitting a linear mixed effects model in R using the package lme4. The regression model is defined as such:

```
fit <- lme4::glmer.nb(outcome ~ type + (1 | random_effect), data)
```

where `outcome` represents count data (hence the negative binomial model), `type` is a binary predictor variable and `random_effect` is a random effect to take into account within-pairs comparisons, as our data are paired (e.g. for each type, we have a pair of observations). Note that this is the most reduced version of the model, but I have other versions with a greater number of predictors encountering the same problem.

I am then calculating bootstrapped confidence intervals using the `confint.merMod` function of lme4:

```
CI <- lme4::confint(fit, method = "boot", level = 0.95, 
                    boot.type = "basic", nsim = 1000)
```

The problem I am encountering is that the estimates of the regression model are falling outside of the calculated confidence interval, e.g. the estimate of the intercept is 1.881 but the confidence interval around the intercept is given as 1.745-1.812. In contrast, using the 'Wald' method produces confidence intervals that surround the estimates.

What could be causing such behaviour, and how might I best address this?

Comment: Are you familiar with bootstrap’s possible bias and bias corrected bootstrap? I’m afraid without a reproducible example I can’t give a detailed answer.

Comment: Also, do you know what exactly boot.type of basic refers do?